# Qt QTreeWidgetItem - adding children after cleaning old ones

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTreeWidget` where upon clicking the expand of an item - when the `itemExpanded` signal is emitted, I use an algorithm to construct a `QList<QTreeWidgetItem*>` and add it to the expanded item with `QTreeWidgetItem::addChildren`.

This works, however if I collapse and expand it again, it adds more children, so I get duplicates. So I have to remove the old children first. For that I use `qDeleteAll(item->takeChildren())` and then I add the new ones with `addChildren`. The thing is, it doesn't work for some reason. It remains empty.

Is there some standart way of performing such an operation?

Comment: I don't think you should add and remove items using the the itemExpanded signal.  Try doing that in a separate process and update the items when they actually need a change.

Comment: What do you mean? I need to add them when it's expanded. I'm working with a very deep directory and I can't add everything, I have to only add what is expanded - when it's expanded.

Comment: I'm not an expert with QTreeWidget, but I suspect it's due to this feature 
"If the child has already been inserted somewhere else it wont be inserted again."

Comment: But I'm inserting a new one with the same text, that's why I want to remove all the old ones and just add the new ones.

Comment: Are you making a new QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> or reusing the old container?  Also qDeleteAll does not remove the items from the container, it only deletes the heap memory, the pointers are still persisting in the list.  Are you calling QList::clear() after you delete?

Comment: I am creating new `QTreeWidgetItem` objects and pushing them to the new list. Then I use `takeItems` to take the old one out of the expanded item and I use `addChildren` to add my new one. However the result is - it doesn't get the new children and remains empty. I use `qDelete` on the old ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you really want to use a QTreeView with a custom QAbstractItemModel. Yes, that may look a bit scary, if you have never done this before, but the key advantage is that in this approach, the view will ask you for item data, if and when it is needed, without you having to pre-fill it.

Alternatively, do consider the advice given by Michael Boone: Instead of deleting all child items, then re-adding them, why don't you just check whether child items have already been added (optionally updating them, if required)?